# How can i regenerate all files from root cpanel (public_html)?

Tags: cpanel

I remove accidently all files from root on File manager in cpanel.
How can i regenerate all folders for my site again (public_html, ssl, mail, all)?

My site doesn't work right now because i delete all files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have deleted all the files the best thing to do would be to terminate that cPanel account and then re-create it. You have no files inside anyway, so there's nothing to lose!